# How does one write an SQL query to add up a total of balances for each user's most recent transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes the following columns:

UserName (nvarchar), TransactionDateTime (datetime), Balance (money).

Each time a user makes a transaction, this is recorded as a row in the table.

The majority of users have multiple transactions stored in the database.

I want to write an SQL query that takes the most recent TransactionDateTime for each UserName and then creates a total of all these balances.

I do not want to include the balances of any user transactions apart from the most recent for each user.

I hope that I have explained this clearly. Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and SQL management studio 2008.

Thanks,
Nelson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to accomplish this:

SELECT SUM(Balance) AS Total_Balance
FROM tablename a 
WHERE TransactionDateTime = (
SELECT MAX(TransactionDateTime)
FROM tablename b 
WHERE a.UserName = b.UserName)

Answer (score 0):

```
  select UserName, max(TransactionDateTime), sum(Balance)
  from tablename group by Username Having TransactionDateTime=max(TransactionDateTime)
```

Comment: Hi Sonam, Thanks for the reply, when I run this query I get the following error:              Column 'TransactionTable.TransactionDateTime' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.